# Counting problem for finding the probability of two pairs in a five card hand.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, poker

I am having trouble understanding what I have wrong in this stats problem for my hw. I am trying to find the probability of getting two pairs in a 5 card hand from a deck of cards. So first we know that
$$P(\text{Two pairs})=\frac{N(\text{Two pairs})}{N(\text{total 5 card hands})}$$
I know the answer to this question is
$$\frac{{13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{11 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 5}},$$
which makes sense because we choose 2 ranks out of the 13 times choose 2 pairs times the last card which will be a different rank. However, I got this answer (which I know is wrong)
$$\frac{{13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{11 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 5}}.$$
My logic was that I first choose each rank separated and then their respective pairs from the rank. I also know that I am overcounting but I do not know why I am wrong specifically. Any help works!

Comment: Suppose the rank chosen for the first pair is aces, and the rank chosen for the second pair is tens. By your count, that would be a different hand than if you chose tens for the first pair and aces for the second pair; however those would obviously lead to the same hand.

Comment: Your expression has ${13 \choose 1}{12 \choose 1}$ in effect for choosing the two different paired values where the correct answer has ${13 \choose 2}$.  Since you are using combinations, the latter is the correct approach while yours double counts

Comment: Also be careful: does "two pairs" include four of a kind or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if you use ${13 \choose 1} {12\choose 1}$ to count the number of distinct pairs, you are considering that order matters, that is, King and Queen, for instance, will be counted twice (K, Q) and (Q, K).

As an exercise, prove: ${13 \choose 2} = \dfrac{1}{2} {13 \choose 1} {12\choose 1}.$